SOC Lab using docker or docker compose
Hello Docker Experts,
I'm planning to build a comprehensive home lab for a Security Operations Center (SOC) and security testing using Docker Compose involves orchestrating multiple services, and each providing specific functions.
I'm currently stuck in the network segmentations  here is my requirement:

Three networks each with their own subnets  External, internal and DMZ
External can communicate to an NGINX container on DMZ  through a firewall iptables container
DMZ can communicate to the internal and vise versa  controlled through FRR container.

Is there a way  using docker to do that using one Docker host instead of buying different computers and I m not interested in using kubernetes .
I have read and played with different apps such as calico tried ipvlan  googled around but i wasted alot of time and didnt get any where.
Any advise or guidance would be appreciated ?

Docker itself controls a lot of the network environment.  If you're trying to simulate Ethernet networks and switches and firewall policies and similar things, you'll need a VM-based setup that simulates these things and gives you more control.  A "DMZ" doesn't make sense in Docker, for example, and a Docker network can't be directly connected to the "outside" however you'd define that.

Thanks, I appreciate it! I think I’ll set up VMware Workstation networks and deploy VMs to host network applications like IPFire, pfSense, FRRouting, etc. I’ll also deploy DNS and AD servers as VMs, and set up three additional VMs on separate networks to serve as my Docker hosts.  The down side is Ithey all vms  .. I will probably use combination of ansible playbooks and docker compose files
